# Asynchronous code to send email notification fails to send email occasionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

My web application in production sometimes fails to send an order email notification. I have never experienced the issue in the test environment.

I do not understand why it is behaving like this way.  Could you please guide me on what is causing the issue?

Below is my code:

```
public async Task SendEmail(int alertID, string body, string subject, List<string> ccemailToUserList)
        {
            try
            {

                using (var dbcontext = new MyDbContext())
                {

                    List<string> emailRecipients = new List<string>();

                    Alert emailAlert = new Alert();
                    emailAlert = dbcontext.Alerts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == alertID);


                    body = body.Replace("[[ordertype]]", emailAlert.Description);

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    var mailFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPFrom"].ToString();
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom);
                    mail.To.Add(emailAlert.Recipients);
                    foreach (var ccEmail in ccemailToUserList)
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(ccEmail);
                    }

                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Port = 25;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"].ToString();
                    mail.Subject = emailAlert.Description+ " - " + subject;
                    mail.Body = body;



                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorService.LogError(ex, "Email Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Put the exceptions you are getting

Comment: I do not get any error, Out of 100 times, 4 times email does not send. I never have experienced in test environment.

Comment: Is not being send or is not being received? First check if mail server sends these emails.

Comment: Let me pull the exception message.

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Relaying denied    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)    
at MyApplication.EmailService.<SendEmail>d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: Another kind of exception I could see is :System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at MyApplication.EmailService.<SendEmail>d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: I have checked with mail server, they never had any email blocked. Issues is recipients do not get email. It is happening random. For example, If user place order for an item 3 times. 2 times vendor gets order emails. And this does not happen every day. It happens occasionally.

Comment: Regarding your NullReferenceException, you probably should implement a check if your parameters are null, especially ccemailToUserList. Regarding the error with your email server being unavailable, you at least need some kind of retry logic. A queue where you keep unsent mails until they were sent without exceptions would be even better (just watch out to implement an increasing delay and a maximum amount of tries to prevent endless loops).

Comment: How do I achieve queuing the process?

Comment: Where is the `emailDescription` defined?

Comment: @ Theodor, that was my mistake while editing the code in question section. emailDescription is emailAlert.Description. I am going to edit that line. Thank you.